on-run-end failed. error: 'data_quality_log' is undefined
I am working to set hook to load into DB. Set-up for dbt_project.yml file
on-run-end:
- "{{ data_quality_log(results) }}"

Following is the header of my data_quality_log.sql file
{% macro data_quality_log(results) %}
{%- if execute -%}
    {%- set parsed_results = data_quality_parse(results) -%}
    {%- if parsed_results | length  > 0 -%}
        {% set insert_dbt_results_query -%}
    .......

Upon running the dbt test I received following error:
on-run-end failed, error:
'data_quality_log' is undefined

Any ideas on how to solve?
